# How to get the miner address of a block with infura Rinkeby endpoint?

Tags: mining, json-rpc, infura, rinkeby, clique

I've read some docs online that to get the miner/sealer/signer address of a particular block that runs with the Ethereum PoA/Clique consensus (the Rinkeby testnet for example), I need to call the *clique_getSnapshot* RPC interface. However when I tried it with a infura Rinkeby endpoint, it returns "*The method clique_getSnapshot does not exist/is not available*" error.

So is there any way where I can get the miner/sealer/signer address of a particular block on the Rinkeby testnet with an infura Rinkeby endpoint? For example on etherscan it shows that block 4753195 is mined by 0x7ffC57839B00206D1ad20c69A1981b489f772031

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/block/4753195

How may I get that info?

======

Thanks to @Ha ĐANG , I've now come to this stage:

```
Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxx"); // my infura Rinkeby endpoint
ejutils = require("ethereumjs-utils");

(async () => {
  blk = await web3.eth.getBlock(4753195);  

  blkhash = blk.hash;
  console.log(blkhash);  
  // 0xdfd0a441a76d0f54bea2b61963871a61bca5eb4adf76f15d60e2d3c7b19cf191 Correct!!

  extdat = blk.extraData;
  console.log(extdat); 
  // 0xd883010900846765746888676f312e31322e34856c696e7578000000000000009e4d991ca30e6ff6782058da4b958eb180e54f3af99f00afa9d42ea01c08b1134664c21f408d79c87d93a6ce83354a68d8f0d3fea99bc796029875563acceef801 Correct!!

  msg = ejutils.toBuffer(blkhash);
  sig = extdat.slice(-130);
  r = "0x" + sig.slice(0, 64);
  s = '0x' + sig.slice(64, 128);
  v = '0x' + sig.slice(128, 130);
  v = parseInt(v) + 27;
  pub = ejutils.ecrecover(msg, v, r, s);
  addr = ejutils.pubToAddress(pub);
  addr = ejutils.bufferToHex(addr);
  console.log(addr);
  // 0xe2877298e8cf1046ae9f3231e17f73fe85282590 Wrong :(

})();
```

So any idea what went wrong in the above code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I've read some docs online that to get the miner/sealer/signer address
> of a particular block that runs with the Ethereum PoA/Clique consensus
> (the Rinkeby testnet for example), I need to call the
> clique_getSnapshot RPC interface. However when I tried it with a
> infura Rinkeby endpoint, it returns "The method clique_getSnapshot
> does not exist/is not available" error.

→ We can only call `clique_getSnapshot` on node's console, we cannot call it via JSON RPC API.

> So is there any way where I can get the miner/sealer/signer address of
> a particular block on the Rinkeby testnet with an infura Rinkeby
> endpoint? For example on etherscan it shows that block 4753195 is
> mined by 0x7ffC57839B00206D1ad20c69A1981b489f772031

→ You can call [eth_getBlockByNumber](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getblockbynumber) JSON RPC API on [infura](https://infura.io/)  endpoint to get the block info then figure out the miner in the block data by using `ecrecover` function to recover the miner's address from their digital signature storing in the last 130 hex charaters in the  **block.extraData**.

Below are snippet code to use `ecrecover` in golang code

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/clique"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/xxxxxx")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    block, err := client.BlockByNumber(context.Background(), big.NewInt(4753195))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    pubkey, err := crypto.Ecrecover(clique.SealHash(block).Bytes(), block.Extra[len(block.Extra)-65:])
    log.Println(pubkey)
    var signer common.Address
    copy(signer[:], crypto.Keccak256(pubkey[1:])[12:])
    log.Println(err)
    log.Println(signer.Hex())
}
```

and output the same miner address `0x7ffC57839B00206D1ad20c69A1981b489f772031` with `mined by` on [etherscan.io](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/block/4753195)

Comment: Could you elaborate on HOW may I figure out the miner in the block data? With Rinkeby, the "miner" field in the result is always "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", and I don't see any field remotely resembling "recents" or "snapshot" or anything looking like the miner address shown on the etherscan page.

Comment: OK, I update the answer. PTAL

Comment: could you be more specific? I know there's a web3.eth.personal.ecRecover method, but it needs to pass two parameters which are "dataThatWasSigned" and "signature", so what should I pass as those two parameters? thanks.

Comment: miner sign for the block then data should be the hash block's header itself but honestly I dont know exactly how to make it to pass to ecRecover() function :)

Comment: try to use block.hash as input for `dataThatWasSigned` and block.extraData as input for `signature`

Comment: and note that the `signature` is the last `130` hex characters in the block.extraData. Normally, it will go after  `00000000000000`

Comment: please see my edited question, I seem to be able to compute an address with the ecrecover method, but it's different from what the etherscan shows. Any idea what's wrong in the code? Thanks.

Comment: yeah, I also just updated my answer to add simple golang code; the input data is not block.hash, it's the sealhash calculated by a function in the consensus.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to implement the code in nodejs, so any idea how to compute this "SealHash" with nodejs? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you try to use this code `await web3.currentProvider.send("clique_getSignersAtHash",['block hash value']);` to call `clique_getSignersAtHash` directly?

Comment: I got the good old "The method clique_getSignersAtHash does not exist/is not available" error message with the infura Rinkeby endpoint :(

Comment: hmm, so we need to port SealHash() method from golang into nodejs by using this lib `https://github.com/ethereumjs/rlp`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for helps from @Ha ĐANG I finally reached this solution

```js
    const Web3 = require("web3");
    const web3 = new Web3("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/xxxxxx"); // infura Rinkeby endpoint
    const eju = require("ethereumjs-utils");

    (async () => {
      let blk = await web3.eth.getBlock(4753195);  

      let header = [
        eju.toBuffer(blk.parentHash),
        eju.toBuffer(blk.sha3Uncles),
        eju.toBuffer(blk.miner),
        eju.toBuffer(blk.stateRoot),
        eju.toBuffer(blk.transactionsRoot),
        eju.toBuffer(blk.receiptsRoot),
        eju.toBuffer(blk.logsBloom),
        parseInt(blk.difficulty),
        parseInt(blk.number),
        parseInt(blk.gasLimit),
        parseInt(blk.gasUsed),
        parseInt(blk.timestamp),
        eju.toBuffer(blk.extraData.slice(0, blk.extraData.length - 130)),
        eju.toBuffer(blk.mixHash),
        eju.toBuffer(blk.nonce)
      ];

      let msg = eju.rlp.encode(header);
      let msghash = eju.keccak256(msg)
      let sig = blk.extraData.slice(-130);
      let r = "0x" + sig.slice(0, 64);
      let s = '0x' + sig.slice(64, 128);
      let v = '0x' + sig.slice(128, 130);
      v = parseInt(v) + 27;
      let pub = eju.ecrecover(msghash, v, r, s);
      let addr = eju.pubToAddress(pub);
      addr = eju.bufferToHex(addr);
      console.log(addr);
      // 0x7ffc57839b00206d1ad20c69a1981b489f772031 Correct!!

    })();
```

Took a full hour of trial and error to finally get the correct result. Can't believe it's actually this hard to accomplish such a seemingly easy task. Anyone seeing this please upvote @Ha ĐANG's answer, thanks.

Comment: Magnificient! ^^